# Animation Playing While Loading Scene One to Other in C# Unity3D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need to know about **Animation Playing While Loading Scene One to Other in C# Unity3D**.

I am using the below code to Navigation. It navigates to `Scene2`, but it doesn't looks very good.

```
 Application.LoadLevel ("Scene2");
```

How can I apply a loading animation while the level loads?

Comment: Have you googled this?  http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/39317/animated-loading-screen.html

Comment: Yes,that is also looks like same as `Application.LoadLevel ("Scene2");`.@PhilipPittle

Answer (score 1):

From http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/39317/animated-loading-screen.html:

Create a scene that will be your loading screen, do what you want to do with this scene (an animation or whatever you want). Don't forget to make this small to load.

Create an object with a script and in the Update function of this script just put these lines:

```
if(Application.GetStreamProgressForLevel("Scene2") ==1){
     Application.LoadLevel("Scene2");
}
```

Make sure that you put these scenes in order when publishing:

- LoadScreen
- Scene1
- LoadScreen
- Scene2

The `Application.GetStreamProgressForLevel()` function returns a float number between 0 and 1, you can use this to make a progress bar too.

Additional reading:

- http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/loading-screen.38405/
- http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/adding-loading-screen-while-unity-is-getting-loaded.17298/

Comment: No,Its navigates directly to scene2 like same as above one.@PhilipPittle

Comment: When your application first starts you should call `Application.LoadLevel("LoadScreen")` and that should in turn call your Update script

Answer (score 0):

Create new scene (loading) Coding you're loading screen 
Or use this resource :https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/6354

then after you create the loading scene

use this code (scene (loading)) add the code after the level finish

```
Application.LoadLevel("loading");
```

and on loading scene change the name of level use this to navigate you to next level

```
 Application.LoadLevel("level2");
```